# Initialize static constexpr char array member with conditional operator in class template

Tags: c++, initialization, constexpr

Consider a minimal example

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    // won't compile. how to change?
    static constexpr char sep[3] = std::is_integral<T>::value ? ". " : ", ";

    // many other things ...
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<int>::sep << std::endl;     // prints .
    std::cout << foo<double>::sep << std::endl;  // prints ,
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

- if `T` has an integral type, then `sep` is initialized to `.`
- otherwise, `sep` is initialized to `,`

However, the compiler won't allow this, saying

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

It looks like something must be done in compile time. But I am not sure how to do it.

My question is: **is there anything I can do to achieve this end?**

*Note: Minimal change is most welcome. There ought to be many other things in `foo`. Another consideration is that I want to keep everything about `foo` in header and to leave nothing in source file, if possible.*

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using a brace-enclosed initializer? `char sep[3] = { std::is_integral<T>::value ? '.' : ',', ' ', '\0' };`

Comment: @melpomene No, I haven't. And yes, it looks to solve the problem! If you would like to make it an answer, I will tick. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need the size (`3`) ? if yes, could you use `std::array` instead ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you please elaborate? How to write that line with `std::array`? I didn't realize `std::array` could stand as `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-arrays are not copyable, so you have to work-around that

- Do the check for each character:

  ```
  constexpr char sep[3] = { std::is_integral<T>::value ? '.' : ',', ' ', '\0' };
  ```
- Don't use array but pointer (so you loose size):

  ```
  constexpr const char* sep = std::is_integral<T>::value ? ". " : ", ";
  ```
- Use `std::array`:

  ```
  constexpr std::array<char, 3> sep = std::is_integral<T>::value
     ? std::array<char, 3>{{'.', ' ', 0}}
     : std::array<char, 3>{{',', ' ', 0}};
  ```
- Use reference to array:

  ```
  constexpr char dot_sep[3] = std::is_integral<T>::value ? ". " : ", ";
  constexpr char comma_sep[3] = std::is_integral<T>::value ? ". " : ", ";
  constexpr const char (&sep)[3] = std::is_integral<T>::value ? dot_sep : comma_sep;
  ```

  and provide definition of `dot_sep`/`comma_sep` which are ODR-used.

Comment: Well, if I replace that line with `static constexpr char* sep = std::is_integral<T>::value ? ". " : ", ";` then the compiler (g++ 7.3) would complain `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @fleix: I miss a `const`, fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. This is a good example where when you provide a `constexpr` you still need a `const`, each referring to a different part/level.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use base class with specialization, and put `sep` in the base class:

```
template <bool IsIntegral>
struct foo_base;

template<>
struct foo_base<true>
{
    static constexpr char sep[3] = ". ";
};

template<>
struct foo_base<false>
{
    static constexpr char sep[4] = ",  ";
};


template<typename T>
struct foo : foo_base<std::is_integral_v<T>>
{
    // many other things ...
};
```

But if you don't want others to access the base, you can use private inheritance:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo : private foo_base<std::is_integral_v<T>>
{
    using foo_base<std::is_integral_v<T>>::sep;
    // many other things ...
};
```

## Edit

The advantage of this solution over using a `std::array<char, 3>`, is that this solution plays nicely with functions that accept a reference to C arrays of char. Neither storing `const char*` nor `std::array<char, 3>` have this capability.

For example, if you have functions like:

```
template <std::size_t I>
constexpr int count_nuls(const char (&x)[I])
{
    // Can't use std::count, since it is not constexpr
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (auto ch: x)
        if (ch == '\0')
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

This function can't be used with `std::array`, or with a `const char *`. If there are many functions like that, one may not want to upgrade all of them to `std::array`. For example, this function works perfectly in:

```
static constexpr unsigned nuls = count_nuls(foo<double>::sep);
```

But won't work (without further modification) with `std::array<char, 3>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please give an example to elaborate "this solution plays nicely with functions that accept a reference to C arrays of char"?

Comment: @fleix Added an example for code that only works with C arrays

Comment: Thanks for the illustration! Now I see the point. Say if `sep` has size 3 in one case but size 4 in another, your solution can nicely deal with it. Too bad I can only tick one answer, but definitely your answer deserves my upvote.

Comment: @fleix, the other answer is more  elegant, and in most cases I'd prefer it. But there are cases when the approach of this answer gives better results,.